# What would be the rule for parsing parameterized sql for Netezza to be used with nzsql?

Tags: parameter, netezza, parse

I have a bunch of legacy parametrized SQL templates that were used by nzsql utility for Netezza. See examples here: http://queforum.com/netezza/347918-parameterized-sql-file-input-nzsql.html

**What is the algorithm that nzsql command line utility is using for parsing parameters?**

*Background*: I am writing a SQL generation utility in python and I need to be able to pass the parameters to my legacy parametrized SQL templates and get pure SQL back. For that, I need to mimic the exact rule for what nzsql considers a parameter.

Part of an answer from the forum link above:

You have to specify a colon before the variable name. An example is shown below:

```
select * from :TABLENAME
```

I need to figure out where the parameter name ends. I think it can happen at word bounds, but also a period forces the end of a parameter name, i.e.

```
select * from :DBNAME..TABLENAME
```

I would love to know the exact rules, but so far have not found any documentation.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @nurandi I suppose so ... we are no longer using Netezza :) To answer your actual question - no.